# Wix Toolset - Setting a Property to User Profile Folder path and Program Files

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I am using Properties to set the values of Registry entries.  This is so that on install the first time I have a default value and then on upgrade the current registry value is used.

I need to have a property that sets the path to the user's local folder and to the programs folder.  I know the below code is wrong but how do I do it.  I think at least I want to do a Type 51 custom action but don't understand the documentation.

I believe there are three relevant parts

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SetUserFolder" Before="InstallInitialize"/>
    <Custom Action="SetInstallFolder" Before="InstallInitialize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Custom Action

```
<CustomAction Id="SetUserFolder" Property="UserFolder" Value="[%USERPROFILE]" />
<CustomAction Id="SetInstallFolder" Property="P_InstallFolder" Value="[%PROGRAMFILES]" />
```

The property.

```
<Property Id="P_MyAPPPATH" Value="[P_InstallFolder]MyApp\">
    <RegistrySearch Id="S_MyAppPath" Type="raw" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyApp\Settings" Name="MyAppPath"/>
</Property>
<Property Id="P_MyAPPDB" Value="[UserFolder]\MyApp\MyAppData\">
    <RegistrySearch Id="S_MyAPPDB" Type="raw" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyApp\Settings" Name="MyAppdb"/>
</Property>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using the properties you're defining, you might be able to use some built-in properties to better effect.

Instead of %USERPROFILE, consider [LocalAppDataFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This will avoid your data from being copied between machines as a user roams between machines on a network domain. I'm guessing you don't need that but, if you do, use [AppDataFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and beware of the latencies involved.

Instead of %PROGRAMFILES, consider [ProgramFilesFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This seems to be what you intend.

Comment: Yes Yes i would love to use them.  The problem is how do I get them as the default property of the Property attribute?